# mysql query gets slower with increasing page number

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I use laravel 5.2 with mariadb (ARIA engine) and found that my query for creating a gallery gets slower with increasing page number.

```
select `pics`.`id`, 
       `pics`.`title`, 
       `pics`.`hits`, 
       `pics`.`created_at`, 
       `users`.`username`, 
       `users`.`displayname` 
from `pics` 
left join `users` on `pics`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
order by `pics`.`id` desc 
limit 48 
offset 7776
```

This is the query for the last page (163) (`offset 7776`) which takes about 20ms while page 1 (`offset 0`) needs only 700µs. This is possibly still fast (?), but also  a difference.

Why does it get slower and what could I do to improve it?
Both tables have gaps and get `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE`.

pics table:

```
id  int(11) unsigned Auto-Inkrement  
url varchar(100)     
title   varchar(200)     
text    text     
jahrprod    year(4) NULL     
cat varchar(50)  
hits    int(11) [0]  
username    varchar(30)  
user_id smallint(5) unsigned     
location_id int(11)  
created_at  datetime     
updated_at  datetime
```

`pics.username` is old and will be removed in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember where you "left off".  That way the "Next" page can do `WHERE id > $leftoff ORDER BY id LIMIT 10` very efficiently.  "Prev" page can be done similarly, as can "First" and "Last".  [*More discussion in my blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

Comment: I have changed from ?page=2 to ?pgid=2345 and then `where id < $pgid` as written in both answers. It's faster now on all pages.

Answer (score 3):

when you're using the "limit 48 offset 7776" mysql need to scan all rows(48+7776), along with offset number increase, mysql need to scan more and more rows for "Next page"
To improve this, try:

```
select ... from ... where id > 7776 limit 48
```

or try:

```
select ... from ... where id between 7776 and 7824
```

Comment: Good idea -- _if_ no ids have been deleted.